Is there a notion of infinity multicategories?
I know there are infinity operads, but I could not find anything about infinity multicategories. Is there any such notion or is it just useless to even consider such an object?

You could not find anything because they are basically the same thing. "Colored operad" is a synonym of multicategory, and an oprad is a multicategory with just one object.
Infinity operads are certain kind of 'fibrations' $C \to \textrm{Fin}_*$, a suitable variation of the category of finite sets. The fiber $C_{<1>}$ over the 'set' with one object is the higher analog of the set of objects in a multicategory. If it is contractible (higher analog of "it is a point"), then it's an infinity operad; otherwise, it is an infinity multicategory.
However, I think it's standard terminology to use colored operads in the higher context, maybe even without "colored".
